# Why the code is triggering 'too many renders', why its 'undefined'?

Tags: reactjs, grid

I define:

```
  const countryCode = "ca";
```

..

```
  const [countryKode, setCountryKode] = useState("")
```

..

```
 setCountryKode(countryCode)
 console.log(countryKode)  ???? Should it display the value????
```

..

```
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
          <h1> Country Code: {countryKode}</h1> ?? says countryKode undefined..??
```

Why its not recognizing the 'countryKode'??

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
..
export default function CountryPanel() {
  const classes = useStyles();
 
  const countryCode = "ca";
  const url =
    "https://api.thevirustracker.com/free-api?countryTotal=" + countryCode;
 
    const [globalData, setGlobalData] = useState({});
    const [countryKode, setCountryKode] = useState("")

    setCountryKode(countryCode) ??? TOO MANY RENDERS ..
 
   console.log(countryKode)  ???? Should it display the value????
    
  useEffect(() => {
  
      getData(url);

    async function getData(url) {
      const response = await fetch(url);
      let data = await response.json(); // convert to json
      const countrycode = data.countrydata[0].info.code;
      const countryname = data.countrydata[0].info.title;

      setGlobalData(data.countrydata[0]);

    }

  }, []);

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
          <h1> Country Code: {countryKode}</h1>  ?? says countryKode undefined .why???
      <Grid container spacing={3}>
        {Object.keys(globalData).map((key, ind) => {
          return (
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={4} key={ind}>
              <Paper className={classes.paper} elevation={10}>
                <h3 className={classes.title}>
                </h3>
              </Paper>
            </Grid>
          );
        })}
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}
```

setCountryKode(countryCode)  triggers the following error: Why could that be??

Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
Appreciate your kind help,

Comment: on every rerender you are creating a brand new `countryCode` variable and calling `setCountryKode` every single time. That function updates `state` wich leads to rerender and the same loop happens again and again and again.

Comment: Can you please elaborate since i am new to React and get mixed up in the terminology. What you mean by 'every rerender'??

Comment: Your component is a function and by "re-render" I mean every time it is called. When that happens, line by line in your function body is executed. This is not React specific behavior. What is React specific is that every local `state` update will cause a re-render. You are updating `state` when you call `setCountryKode(countryCode)`. And since this function call is not wrapped in a function or condition, it will be called on every single re-render

Comment: My objective is to take this countrycode as input from user then pass it to fetch api. Secondly, I want to display this code alongwith API output. Whats the best way?

Comment: create a function that is called only when there is user input. If all you want to do is send this input to an API, you wouldn't even have to store it inside local state anymore.

Comment: I need more details along with code if you kindly. I was starting with this:
```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function UserInput() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState(""); // '' is the initial state value

    console.log(input, "input")
 return (
    <div>
      <label>Country Code: </label>
      <input value={input} onInput={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Do I need usestate in this?

Answer (score 1):

You should not use setCountryKode directly inside functional component as it will land you in infinitw loop. You can use it inside effect or make any function inside this functional component. You can initialse it as follows

```
const [countryKode, setCountryKode] = useState("ca")
```

and remove this line

```
  // setCountryKode(countryCode) ??? TOO MANY RENDERS ..
```

Comment: @nktoronto Did the solution help you?

Comment: Hi Raghvender,  Actually, I am taking the countrycode as user input so could be any code. Can not have useState("ca") since user may enter someother code. How do you suggest I handle the user inout and set the countrycode to that??

Comment: Also, my other question:
 return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
          <h1> Country Code: {countryKode}</h1> ?? says countryKode undefined..??

Answer (score 1):

Setting state in the render function will cause another render to trigger. So in this case, your `render` will call `setCountryKode`, which will call render, which will call `setCountryKode`, which will call `render`, and so on and so forth - infinitely.

To prevent this, you should set `countryKode` initially to `countryKode` in `useState`:

```
const countryCode = "ca";
const [countryKode, setCountryKode] = useState(countryCode);
```

or even:

```
const [countryCode, setCountryCode] = useState("ca");
```

Comment: Hi Marlo, Thanks for the detailed explanation. Actually, I am taking the countrycode as user input so could be any code. Can not have useState("ca") since user may enter someother code. How do you suggest I handle the user inout and set the countrycode to that??

Comment: Also, my other question: return ( <div className={classes.root}> <h1> Country Code: {countryKode}</h1> ?? says countryKode undefined..?? –